# Is there a way to import an iCal file into FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm working on a program that parses text and turns it into iCal events. I'm then using `FullCalendar` to display the information inside a google gadget.

I'm currently importing the `.ics` file into my google calendar, making that public, and then pointing `fullCalendar` at it.

However I'm trying to do accomplish without making the information public. Any ideas?

Alternatively, is there any other lightweight customizable javascript calendar that can interpret .iCal?

Ideally I would be able to just use a single day view/single week view and not an entire month view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import iCal (ics) with fullcalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404685/import-ical-ics-with-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 2):

You never said if you using PHP, .NET or what.

So I will assume you use .NET just becuase i use it.

I use this nice DLL Library in .NET
[DDay iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/)

I use it to create iCals so that people can import to iphones,outlook etc. but briefly looking there is a way to serialize it as well, so you could use it anyway you need to.

And Google Calendars are not listed publicly any more because of private security. Only people with the link can access the gCal.. and your the only ones that knows it. If somebody wanted to get sensitive data then no matter what method you used it always has some vulnerably

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a better answer. I was doing the same thing (iCalendar format -> Google Calendar, public -> FullCalendar) but became frustrated with how slowly Google Calendar would update. So instead, I put the data into JSON format for FullCalendar.

So now, the site does (A) iCalendar format for distribution to people (they can add it to their own Google Calendar, iCal software, etc.), and also (2) JSON format for FullCalendar.

The advantage is that I can reformat the JSON "description" part to make it look better with QTip bubbles (html line breaks, css styling).

Answer (score 0):

There is also [jQuery iCalendar](http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html) you should check it out.

And there is [JSON to XML converter](https://web.archive.org/web/20120415040917/http://michalkorecki.com/content/introducing-json-xml-jquery-plugin), it's very useful maybe it can help.

Both can work with any language, you should try them and see which 
one is better for your specific calendar.